# Can we refer to the standard form of a quadratic equation as the general form as well?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, quadratics

I would like to know if we can refer to $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ as the "general form" of a quadratic equation, or is it only called the standard form?

Answer (score 2):

standard form

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
where $x$ represents a variable or an unknown, and $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants with $a\neq 0$.

Also there is this vertex form : $$a(x-h)^2 + k$$

sometimes called the standard form, where $(h,k)$ is the vertex of the parabola made by the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I was always under the impression that this is how they are organized

**General Form:**
$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$

**Standard Form:**
$f(x) = (x-h)^2 + k$

Now if you want to find the **solutions** to $f(x)$, then you employ the equation you have written down. I don't know of a specific name for the equation, I just call it finding the roots...